# JqueryUI draggable - move dragged element in the dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I've got some issues with Javascript (Jquery + JqueryUI)..
I want to drag and drop an element. If it's over an other certain element the element is recreated..
Below I've tried to make a simplified example so you can see what i mean..

How can i move the code of a dragged element properly to a new position in the dom? This should happen on a "over" event. **Not** when i drop it. When i'm "out" of the dropzone the action made before should be reverted. Means the element copied back to it's source, replacing the other new created element with the same id..

Thanks!
Pala

-Edit-:
I've made some changes in the code for better visualization. When I remove this Line:

```
ui.draggable.attr("id", ui.draggable.attr("id") + "_bkp");
```

The "out:" the Code gets in the out-Part.. Problem is, that i have to change that id because otherwise there will be 2 identical ids.
Can I somehow tell jquery, that's still the same element?

```
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style>
        .bigbox{ width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; margin: 10px; border:thin solid black;}
        .box{ width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; border:thin solid black;}
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#draggable_1, #draggable-nonvalid").draggable();
            $("#droppable").droppable({
                over: function(event, ui) {
                    ui.draggable.attr("id", ui.draggable.attr("id") + "_bkp");
                    ui.draggable.appendTo($("#muell"));
                    $('#momo').append('<div id="draggable_1" class="box"><p>I am a new Elemento</p></div>');
                },
                accept: "#draggable_1",
                out: function(event, ui) {
                    $.each($("#muell > div"), function() {
                        var idOfBackedupElement = $(this).attr("id");
                        var origId = $(this).attr("id").replace("_bpk", "");
                        $("#" + origId).replaceWith($("#" + idOfBackedupElement));
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<div id="momo" style="border:thin solid blue;float:left;">
    <div id="draggable_1" class="box" >
        <p>
            Drag me to my target
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="droppable" class="bigbox">
        <p>
            accept: '#draggable'
        </p>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="muell" style="border:thin solid red;float:left;"></div>

</html>
```

Comment: see first of all "out" event will not trigger until you change the id of draggable item from "draggable_1_bkp" to "draggable_1", because you  setting accept to "draggable_1" only. What are you trying to do inside out event? Do you have any example, based on which you trying to do this?